# mimic window function in sas to group rows and calculate the max continuous membership

Tags: sas

I have a table like this showing the id of a member, the beginning and end date of their membership, the days of their membership and the gap between their last membership and current membership period.

- for example, member 11101 started their membership on 3/1/95 and paused their membership on 11/01/97. they renewed their membership on 6/1/97 without a gap. the total days of this span is 822+153=975 days
- he terminated his membership on 11/1/97 and restarted it on 11/10/04. the gap between these two membership are 11/10/04-11/01/97=2565 days

Im trying to find out the longest spans of a certain member's continuous membership, which is 2160 in this case. I think a window function lag/lead is necessary in SQL. however window function is not supported in sql. how can group these periods based on gap days and calculate the max spans?

thank you for the help!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvG3r.jpg)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using, if you want a SQL answer.  Functional programming is quite different.  So, if you want a functional programming answer, then remove the SQL tag.  Are ou using MySQL or Oracle?  They are quite different.  Only tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

This question was originally tagged SQL/MySQL/Oracle.  This answers the original version of the question.

You can summarize the data for each members for a user.  The idea is to sum up the non-zero values of `gap` (which is rather convenient to have).  This defines a group that can be used for aggregation.  And, in this case, you can just sum the gap:

```
select id, sum(span), min(begin_date), max(end_date)
from (select t.*,
             sum(gap) over (partition by id order by begin_date) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by id, grp;
```

For only the longest per id, you can use window functions again:

```
select *
from (select id, sum(span), min(begin_date), max(end_date),
             row_number() over (partition by id order by sum(span) desc) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   sum(gap) over (partition by id order by begin_date) as grp
            from t
           ) t
      group by id, grp
     ) ig
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: hey gordon, thank you, but I just found that sql window function is not supported in sas and. I want to use sas to do this